# zlib.output_compression off - How to test whether PHP compression is really disabled?

Tags: php, .htaccess, compression, zlib

I added

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression off
```

to my .htaccess. I read PHP compression needs to be disabled if I want to get mod_deflate working.

Is there any way to test whether PHP compression is really disabled?

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned PHP isn't picking up the right value from your php.ini, you can use [ini_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) to check it.

If your concern is that PHP is just compressing regardless you can just make an HTTP request by hand (using netcat, telnet, etc.) or snoop on your a request for your browser using the developer tools.  Just make sure request headers include `Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate` and check the `Content-encoding` response header.  However, keep in mind that there could be other offenders here (like mod_deflate, your PHP script, a proxy…).